# Jquery function based on radio button is selection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to call the data-url of a specific radio button based on the current radio button selection after another function was successfully ran.

Here is my radio button group:

```
<form action="/ALS/RejectRecordAnalysis/1" method="post">
    <span id="wrapper_cra" class="form-group">
        <span><label for="">TEST1</label></span>
        <span id="button-spacing">
            <input class="" data-url="/ALS/RejectRecordAnalysisCRA?business=1&amp;_cra_id=1" id="radiobutton1" name="_cra.agency_name" type="radio" value="{ id = 1 }" />  
        </span>   
        <span><label for="">TEST2</label></span>
        <span id="button-spacing"> 
            <input class="" data-url="/ALS/RejectRecordAnalysisCRA?business=1&amp;_cra_id=2" id="radiobutton2" name="_cra.agency_name" type="radio" value="{ id = 2 }" />  
        </span>   
        <span><label for="">TEST3</label></span>
        <span id="button-spacing"> 
            <input class="" data-url="/ALS/RejectRecordAnalysisCRA?business=1&amp;_cra_id=3" id="radiobutton3" name="_cra.agency_name" type="radio" value="{ id = 3 }" />  
        </span>   
        <span><label for="">TEST4</label></span>
        <span id="button-spacing"> 
            <input class="" data-url="/ALS/RejectRecordAnalysisCRA?business=1&amp;_cra_id=4" id="radiobutton4" name="_cra.agency_name" type="radio" value="{ id = 4 }" />  
        </span>   
    </span>
</form>
```

Looking to run from this success block:
**EDIT**  I added a bit of javascript into the success block. However, the .val() function is returning only the id of the radio button selected and throws an error when trying the *$.ajax* call.

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        var checked = $("#wrapper_cra input[type='radio']:checked").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(checked).data('url'),
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: checked,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#scroll-grid").html(result);
                    }
                });
    } else {
         $('#myModalContent').html(result);
         bindForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: specific how? We can't show you how to target something when we don't know why or when it's supposed to be targeted?

Comment: Based on which radio button is selected. My apologies.

Comment: `$('input[name="_cra.agency_name"]:checked')`

Comment: Do you want to check `result.success` then set radio button based on `data-url` value like that `result` has?

Comment: I would like to call that data-url in the selected radio button. I'm using the mvc design pattern and that url then updates my view. However, I want to avoid reloading the entire page. In this case I only want a portion of it reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above problem. In my success block I added the following code:

```
var checked = $("#wrapper_cra input[type='radio']:checked").attr('data-url');
                $.ajax({
                    url: checked,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#scroll-grid").html(result);
                    }
```

The checked variable contains the data-url of the appropriate radio button, then the `$.ajax` function  runs the url, and I am returning an html partial view, with the updated information.